# In-App Purchase in SWIFT - productsRequest delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to do In-App Purchases in my app where "productsRequest" delegate is not called.

I tried to get the product's information as below,

```
func getProductInfo()
{
    let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.productValue);
    let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    productsRequest.start();
}
```

Then i wrote the delegate methods. But this delegate method `productsRequest - didReceiveResponse` is not getting called.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue in tvOS. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question, I feel obliged to answer.

I tried your code, and for me, it worked.

Some things to check:

- did you add the 'SKProductsRequestDelegate' to your class?
- did you add the correct function in your class?

  ```
  func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
  println("received response")
  ```

  }

that should do the trick :-)